# How to restrict the type of input given to the function Input[]?

Tags: input, data-types

The function `Input[]` when evaluated displays a dialog box where one can enter any character. My question is how do I restrict the input only to a certain type such as numbers or string? I know there is `InputString` that takes in only strings.

This is what I have tried:

```
x = Input["Enter a number"];
While[Head[x] == Symbol, x = Input["Enter a number"]]
```

I believe there is a better solution than this. Can anyone help?

**Edit**

I am aware of the `InputField` function. However, I am trying to implement something with the **Wolfram Engine** and that does not have a front end and I will be using it from the command prompt. Hence, I need to know a way to restrict the input type for the function Input.

Comment: Then just check the result, if it's not what you want, prompt again.

Comment: For the WE I'd go with your approach and upgrade it a little: `While[Not@MatchQ[x, _String | _?NumericQ], 
 x = Input["Enter a number or a string"]]`